# С# Каким способом открыть файл и вытащить из строки конкретный набор символов?

Tags: c#

Есть файл, в котором 1 строка из 5 тыс. хаотичных символов. Нужно из этой строки достать неизвестный набор знаков, на позиции между 2549 и 2561 символом (10 знаков) и записать их в новый файл.
Хотел сделать перебор `foreach` символов, но `FileStream` с ним не работает и вообще я не уверен что правильным способом его открыл, но в консоль выводит всё что в файле. Только начинаю изучение. Прошу помощи.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Corvette
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)+$@"\file.txt";

            FileStream myFile = File.OpenRead(path);

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {                
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);

                Console.WriteLine(file.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Использовать Substring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант попроще:

```cs
int firstSymbolPos = 2550;
int lastSymbolPos = 2560;

string s = File.ReadAllText(path).Substring(firstSymbolPos, lastSymbolPos - firstSymbolPos);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Вариант посложнее:

```cs
static int symbolsOffset = 0;
static int lastSymbolPos = 6;

static byte[] ReadBytes(Stream stream, int firstSymbolPos, int lastSymbolPos)
{
    stream.Position = firstSymbolPos;
    int count = lastSymbolPos - firstSymbolPos;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        bytes[i] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
    return bytes;
}
```

Почему бы и нет

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял как с этим взаимодействовать

Comment: А если Unicode? Вариант посложнее не сработает ведь?

Comment: Зачем цикл в конце, если можно просто `stream.Read(bytes, 0, count);`?

Comment: Но это решение с потоком может не сработать в целом, если попадется хотя-бы один символ юникода, занимающий больше одного байта. Но можно попробовать со `StreamReader` сделать потоковое чтение.

Comment: Он читает до конца, а не `count`. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader_Read_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: @aepot а если со `StreamReader`, то получается это `1?2?3?` вместо `123`

Comment: Кажется, вы в кодировках запутались.